# Google Tag Manager creates empty buttons at the bottom of my page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-tag-manager

As soon as I implement this script

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-WP57CBK');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

every action which the user takes makes a blank button at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Is your CSS setup to display:none on things like script tags and router-outlet etc.?

Comment: @BenRacicot yes, it is.

Comment: Could your code have some own implementations of `dataLayer`. If yes, try changing `dataLayer` to some other value in GTM snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally a custom HTML tag setup inside of that GTM that writes out `<button></button>` to the page, and is set to trigger off the `gtm.click` event, which is not filtered by elements, so is firing off any click made by the user inside the document.

[image: Screenshot]

If you control that GTM, you need to remove or modify that tag, and if you don't you need to talk to who does and tell them the same thing.

Comment: Where did you get a link to his page?

Comment: @Matus I didn't need one - he included the full GTM ID (`GTM-WP57CBK`) in his code, which means I can look at the code GTM generates for his account and how his GTM container is configured. Done by either placing his code in a HTML file and loading it up, or accessing directly at [https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WP57CBK](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WP57CBK).